# Fitting data points using trigonometric functions

Tags: fitting, data, trigonometry

I want to curve fit some data points using a specific linear combination of trigonometric functions with the help of *NonLinearModelfit* as per the following code:

```
points = {{-5, 0.1768}, {-4, 0}, {-3, 0.5863},
{-2,0}, {-1, 0.3535}, {0, 0}, {1, 0.3535}, {2, 0}, {3,0.5863}, {4, 0}, 
{5,0.1768}};
model = a*Sin[b*x] + c*Sin[d*x];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[points, model, {a, b, c, d}, x]
Show[ListPlot[points, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fit[x], {x, -5, 5}]]
```

However, I got the following output which doesn't fit the data altogether:

```
FittedModel[-2.2204*10^-16 Sin[2.6912 x] - 1.1102*10^-16 Sin[4.6912 x]]
```

A guidance on how to go about evaluating this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your data is symmetric about $x = 0$:  for example, you have the points {-1, 0.3535} and {1, 0.3535}.  Meanwhile, your model necessarily satisfies $f(x) = -f(-x)$, regardless of the values of $a, b, c, d$.  Since `NonlinearModelFit` minimizes the least-squares distance from the data points to the curve, the best fit for this model will set the amplitude of the sine waves to zero, so that the curve becomes $f(x) = 0$, which is equally far from the points at $x = \pm 1$.  (Any non-zero amplitude would give a larger least-squares error.)  This is exactly the result that Mathematica has given you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with a mathematical issue in curve-fitting, not a problem with Mathematica.

Comment: The data size 11 is too small to make reliable conclusions.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I have now understood the issue in my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the model chosen is inadequate for the dataset (this is a variation on VTC due to simple mistake). As such, this isn't really a problem with Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to choose a model that can fit the data. First, the data is not zero mean, so you need to add a constant. Second, sinusoids have phase, so you need to add a phase term.

```
model = e + a*Sin[b*x + f] + c*Sin[d*x + g];
fit = NonlinearModelFit[points, model, {a, {b, 2}, c, {d, 4}, e, f, g}, x]
```

With that said, there is a reason that one usually uses Fourier methods to do decompositions of functions into sinusoids.